# Laravel: Refresh response()->file

Tags: php, laravel-5, browser-cache

In Laravel I use this route

```
Route::get('admin/showBill/{file}','Admin\FileController@showBill');
```

and this code

```
class FileController extends AuthController
{
  public function showBill($file)
  {
    $path = storage_path('app/bills/' . basename($file)  );
    if(!\File::exists($path)) return back();
    return response()->file($path);
  }
```

to display a pdf from my storage folder.

So if I have the pdf `bill-1.pdf` in my `/storage/app/bills/` folder, then I can view it with the url

```
example-domain.com/admin/showBill/bill-1.pdf
```

The problem is that if I open that pdf with the browser, replace it, and refresh (F5) the page, then the old bill is shown. I guess its because its stored in the cache. Can I force Laravel to show the new replaced file?

I tried

```
 public function showBill($file)
 {
    $path = storage_path('app/bills/' . basename($file)  );
    if(!\File::exists($path)) return back();
    $path  .= '?v='. time();
    return response()->file($path);
 }
```

But then Laravel tells me that this file does not exist. I am looking for a  solution where I have not to rename the pdf file.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're replacing the right file?

If so, place this `dd()`. I've created an endpoint, response an empty pdf file - viewed it - replaced it with a content-filled pdf file and it works just fine when I replace it.

Edit: Also, you should validate the $file variable, using either a formrequest or validating in the controller.

```
public function showBill($file)
 {
    $path = storage_path('app/bills/' . basename($file));
    if(!\File::exists($path))  { 
     dd("Quite possibly the problem is here, on the redirect back");
    }
    return response()->file($path);
 }
```

Comment: Alright I try to find that out. What kind of validation would you recommend for the `$file` variable? I use basename to make sure its not a path. Filenames can even consist of whitespaces and utf8 chars, so I dunno what to check except if file exists. And the file must exists, otherwise browser should redirect me back.